Grid displays content as rows and not columns
I have a very simple index.tsx file which should render a grid with several columns and rows.
I am taking the example code as is from: https://v6.mantine.dev/core/simple-grid/
This is how it should look like 
And this is how my webpage renders:

The source code is:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { MantineProvider, SimpleGrid } from '@mantine/core';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MantineProvider>
      <SimpleGrid cols={3}>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </SimpleGrid>
    </MantineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Things that I've tried:

Initially the UI was in several objects; I removed all and added it to the top-most layer, without file dependencies. Still same result
Removed all CSS just in case something was causing it. Still same results.
Changed from "div" to other components such as "p" or "Card" components, with same result.

My feeling is that there must be something forcing the divs to take 100% of the width causing the Grid not to be able to place several divs next to each other, but I don't know what else to try.
Any tip would be appreciated.

I think you should load the CSS of Mantine, looking at the doc, you should use the provider as this: <MantineProvider withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS>

There was some dependency issue. I have removed the "mantine" and "emotion" from the project's package.json.
I have reinstalled it by running:
npm install @mantine/core @mantine/hooks @emotion/react

and it's displaying the grid as expected!
